# How to retrieve current route info from Google Navigation in Android

Tags: android

Is there anyway to get the current route information from android google navigation?

For instance people might choose alternative route, avoid tolls, etc. My requirement is to replicate the current route a user has customised and try replicate that on another android device as close as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Navigation has no documented and supported API. Hence, one hopes that what you want is not possible, as it would represent a privacy and security flaw.

Comment: That's my impression as well. Was hoping there's something some where i dunno about that could solve my problem. Thanks.